Tracking App Installs for facebook campaign using Expo and react-native-fbsdk-next
I’m trying to track installs with react-native-fbsdk-next in my React Native app. However, I keep getting the following message when I try to run an App Install campaign on Facebook:
For optimization goal APP_INSTALLS, application_id needs to be valid. Please set it in the Promoted Objects.

I have followed the installation guide provided in the react-native-fbsdk-next documentation and can see Install Events on Facebook Events Manager.
Here is my current code:
import { Settings } from 'react-native-fbsdk-next';
import { getTrackingPermissionsAsync, requestTrackingPermissionsAsync } from 'expo-tracking-transparency';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

useEffect(() => {
  const requestPermissions = async () => {
    try {
      const { status } = await getTrackingPermissionsAsync();

      if (status !== 'granted') {
        const { status: newStatus } = await requestTrackingPermissionsAsync();
        if (newStatus === 'granted') {
          Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true);
        } else {
          Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(false);
        }
      } else {
        Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true);
      }

      Settings.initializeSDK();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to request tracking permissions:", error);
      // Handle error appropriately, possibly showing a message to the user
    }
  };

  setTimeout(async () => {
    await requestPermissions();
  }, 2000);
}, []);

1.Authorized Ads Account ID: I have ensured that my ads account ID is authorized.
2.Facebook App Configuration: Double-checked that the application_id is set correctly in both the Facebook app dashboard and in my app’s code.
